# Migrate from latest android sdk to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I developed a project using android sdk and now I want to open it using android studio.
The online android tutorial says that you should export to .gradle but I don't have this option and I have the latest update.
So how could I migrate to android studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Android Studio` is based on `Intellij IDEA` (now it is 99% same as `Intellij IDEA Community Edition`). So, you can import your project in Android Studio: **File** -> **Import Project...** -> **"PATH to your project"**.

Comment: This most definitely will not work if your project is moderately complex.

Comment: if your project is moderately complex and you haven't used maven or ant in your project, then you need to specify dependencies by itself in project properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your SDK, then you can export it with .gradle in Eclipse. After that you can import it in Android Studio.

Comment: That MIGHT work for a simple project. I've been battling with this for a few days now. My project is very complex with a lot of sub-projects and libraries.

Comment: I can't help you with libaries and sub-projects. I've only tried it with simple projects.